# How to install qt4 in alpine 3.12

Tags: qt4, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

How do I install `qt4` in alpine by using `apk add`?

It seems, that it is not anymore in the list.

Do I have any chance?

Comment: Did you mean, Alpine 3.12?

Comment: Correct, 3.12 it is

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Qt 4 has been removed in Alpine 3.10, and superseded by Qt 5:
https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.10.0-released.html

This is the removal commit, according to which, the Qt4 community Alpine package has been unmaintained for a while prior to being removed:
https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/8515

Alpine doesn't keep old package versions in its catalogue, so once a package is removed, it is usually for good. `qt4` may be found with some very old images, but even if you manage to successfully extract it, it probably won't be compatible with Alpine 3.12.

Sadly, for having Qt4 on Alpine, it looks like you'll have to build it from source, unless it is revived by the Alpine community.